# Using OpenPIV tutorial

Tags: python

I'm trying [this openPIV tutorial](https://openpiv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial1.html) to measure the speed of a river branch. But I'm not getting the velocity vectors with the images I have. I was also unable to reproduce the velocity vectors with the tutorial images. Can someone with experience in this library help?

Return the velocity vectors with the tutorial

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. It might help to add some relevant tags -- maybe [tag:fluid-dynamics] and [tag:physics] (but I'm not a physicist by any means). Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce their output. Can you provide more information about which part you're having trouble with? Do you get incorrect output, no output, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, the images were not the same. I fixed the problem and was able to reproduce. Do you know how to read the particle velocity value?